# Facebook won't crawl my site's URL

Tags: metadata, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to get Facebook to acknowledge the OpenGraph tags I've placed on my page.  When I go to the Facebook Debugger, it seems to think that I have placed none of these tags on my page and when I go to the 'Scraped URL' it does not show the proper tags, and some other markup for this release seems to be missing.  The actual generated source is different than what Facebook is reporting.  Here's what the OG tags look like on my page:

```
<META property="og:image" content='http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/DeluxeForms/BB_158'>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="580767460" />
<meta property="og:url" itemprop="url" content="http://bagsandbowsonline.preprod.deluxe.com/shopdeluxe/catalog/productDetails.jsp?prodId=15-8&referer=RECS">
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title" itemprop="name" content="Kraft Paper Shoppers Cub, 8 1/4 x 4 1/4 x 10 3/4&quot;" />
<meta property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Kraft Paper Shoppers Cub, 8 1/4 x 4 1/4 x 10 3/4&quot;">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Bags and Bows Online" />
```

Per the documentation, my understanding is that pages get crawled by FB's spiders

1. once every 24 hours
2. when one of the fb: admins 'likes' that page
3. when the page is run through the Facebook Debugger.

I'm not seeing any URL redirects in the debugger. Furthermore, Google doesn't have any issues with this page, and the implimentation is a near direct copy of what we're doing on a different site in which these meta tags are properly read.  Does anyone know what could be causing this odd behavior?

My page is located at:
http://bagsandbowsonline.preprod.deluxe.com/shopdeluxe/catalog/productDetails.jsp?prodId=15-8&referer=RECS

The debugger details for this page is at:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbagsandbowsonline.preprod.deluxe.com%2Fshopdeluxe%2Fcatalog%2FproductDetails.jsp%3FprodId%3D15-8%26referer%3DRECS

And the 'Scraped URL' is at the bottom of the Debugger's page.

**UPDATE:**

I pasted a near exact copy of my webpage on a different webserver, and Facebook crawled it correctly.  The plot thickens.

Comment: Are you sure that your page has those meta tags as I could not find either of them at the your website's link you have provided ?

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure.  Could you provide a pastebin of what generated source you're getting?

Comment: Sure, its [here](http://pastebin.com/VCviHz5f), and contains all the contents within `<head>` tag. Although I have removed the JavaScript embedded in your page in question within `<head>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this.  It's weird though...here's what I'm seeing at that same URL, having removed JS: http://pastie.org/8066698

I realized that there's a `<div>` in the header just after the OG tags, which I fixed a while ago but it seems that new code hasn't been deployed to this environ yet.  How are you getting that source?  Just going to the page and pressing 'view source'?